# how to make the conditioanl relation variable in model in yii

Tags: yii

For example i am having the 3 tables.

1) Tab1 having 3 fields for primary members details.

```
----tab1_id(PK)
----fname
----lname
```

Data like :

```
1-----test_firstname------test_lastname
2-----test2_firstname------test2_lastname
```

2) Tab2 having 4 fields for secondary members details.

```
----tab2_id(PK)
----fname
----lname
----tab1_id(FK)
----count
```

Data like :

```
1----test1_firstname-----test1_lastname-----1-----1
2----test2_firstname-----test2_lastname-----1-----2
3----test1_firstname-----test1_lastname-----2-----1
```

and

3) Tab_data having combine details of the primary and secondary based upon the flag count field.

```
----tab_data_id
----operation
----tab1_id(FK)
----count(FK)
```

Now, how can i write the conditional relation for the tab_data model class. 
I want to if count==0 then self belongs to tab1 using tab1_id field and if count>0 then self belongs to tab2 using tab1_id and count filed.......

is it posssible in YII...!!!

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But its a bad design.

```
'relation1' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'tab1', 'ref_id', 'condition' => 'count > 0'),
'relation2' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'tab2', 'ref_id', 'condition' => 'count = 0'),
```

Refer this Yii Forum:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/20018-conditional-relation/

Comment: thanks for the reply.. then what is the approach for this case...!! have to manage the parent child records relation in single table and have to make the relation based upon the refrence..?? and also is it possible to pass multiple fields for reference id..??

Comment: For parent_child relation, you can follow my answer as it is. You can't pass the multiple fields for reference id (upto my knowledge).